# Custom label in enumerate prints "label" before the items

Tags: enumerate, optional-arguments

I followed the demo in Customizing enumerated lists Using packages in [LaTeX/List Structures](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures). The code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries Exercise (i):]
    \item 5 + 7 = 12
    \item 9 + 1 = 10
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

However I got the unexpected output,
[image]

when I remove "label=" in the enumerate option, the output does not show "label=".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries Exercise (i):]
    \item 5 + 7 = 12
    \item 9 + 1 = 10
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So how to use **label** in enumerate?

This question has been solved. The label option is provided by package enumitem. The right code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label = \bfseries Exercise \roman*:]
    \item 5 + 7 = 12
    \item 9 + 1 = 10
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are mixing the syntax of the `enumerate` package (which does *not* know the `label=...` syntax) with the one of the `enumitem` package (which *does* know it)

Comment: The output in your second example is not right, see *Exerciise*. This is because the `i` in the word `Exercise` is interpreted as a special character.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your list is more like an `enumerate` rather than an itemize. It is recommended here to use the `enumitem` package and `\setlist` which accepts many parameters as options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\bfseries Exercise (\roman*):}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 5 + 7 = 12
  \item 9 + 1 = 10
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `enumerate` manual, there is no `label=<...>` syntax.

The letter `a` in `label=` is interpreted as `\alph`, this is why your output is

- libel
- liibel

etc.

You should write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries {Exercise} (i):]
    \item 5 + 7 = 12
    \item 9 + 1 = 10
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note that you have to use `{Exercise}` in order to avoid interpretation of `i` as `\roman`.