# While using \tab, long line of text jumps to the next line inside an itemize environment

Tags: spacing, enumitem, tabto

In order to write a description of a list of items inside an `itemize` environment I use the `\tab` command. However it produces pretty large spaces, making long lines of text jump to the next line, as you can see in the following picture:

[image: List of items and tab]

I would like to have the long line of text of the third item with the same tabulation as the other items.

Additionally, I would like to know if it is possible to control the `\tab` spacing.

**Note:** Answers that produce a **bulleted list** will be preferred.

---

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.75truecm,bottom=1.75truecm,left=1.75truecm,right=1.75truecm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
        \item Lion
        \tab{This is the description of the first item.}

        \item Elephant
        \tab{This is the description of the second item.}

        \item Rabbit
        \tab{This is the description of the third item, which turns out to be a little longer and jumps to the next line.}

        \item Horse
        \tab{This is the description of the fourth item.}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: a better approach is to use the facilities of `enumitem`.  using tabbing of any sort in an `itemize` environment is going to result in undesirable spacing.

Comment: Thanks barbara, I would be grateful if you could shed some light on which facilities in particular should I look at.

Comment: not being a regular user of `enumitem` myself, i have to check the documentation (`texdoc enumitem`).  since you are numbering the items, using `enumerate` instead of `itemize` seems appropriate, with a modification of the `label`.  i think the answer to this question covers the important information: [Custom label in enumerate prints “label” before the items](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/260849/579).  if it *does* answer your question, can we close this as a duplicate?

Comment: The example I posted is just a MWE that I made for clarity purposes. My real case has names that come from variables of a program source code, which do not follow any pattern. Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my question with more suitable item names.

Comment: since your labels vary in content, you should consider using the optional label that is available for `\item[...]`.  it may be necessary to adjust the indentation if the lengths of the labels vary.  i'll try to concoct an answer if someone else doesn't get there first.  (i have to stop to do something else now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with the description environment and `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.75truecm,bottom=1.75truecm,left=1.75truecm,right=1.75truecm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox} {}
\newlist{bulletdescr}{description}{1}
\setlist[bulletdescr]{noitemsep, labelwidth=0.5\linewidth, leftmargin=0.5\linewidth, labelsep=0pt, font=\normalfont}
\AtBeginEnvironment{bulletdescr}{\let\olditem\item \renewcommand\item[1][]{\olditem[{\textbullet\enspace}#1]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{bulletdescr}
 \item[Item 1]
 This is the description of the first item.

 \item[Item 2]
 This is the description of the second item.

 \item[Item 3]
This is the description of the third item, which turns out to be a little longer and jumps to the next line.

 \item[item 4]
 This is the description of the fourth item.
 \end{bulletdescr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.75truecm,bottom=1.75truecm,left=1.75truecm,right=1.75truecm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=3cm, itemindent=0pt,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=3cm]
        \item[Lion]
        This is the description of the first item.

        \item[Elephant]
        This is the description of the second item.

        \item[Rabbit]
        This is the description of the third item, which turns out to be a little longer and jumps to the next line.

        \item[Horse]
        This is the description of the fourth item.
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to add bullet in front of item description, otherwise adding it on every item?

Comment: @pzorba75 see the enumitem documentation which shows how to style the descrioption list items, you can start the formatting command with `\textbullet`